# SharePoint list - How to limit items in list with formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, power-automate, flow

I have SharePoint list, with two columns. First is `Name` and second is `email`
how to create a permission or formula to limit items by `Name` or `email` for each user.

My goals is if in column name or email is mine name or email, this item see only me, nobody else.

I tried filter and permissions, but I had problem to lock it for each user.

Any advice please?

Comment: Are you creating item with your name & email or someone else? If current user creates items with their name & email, you can use OOTB item level permissions from list settings else you have to create a power automate flow to break permissions on items.

Comment: Other user creater item, and add my name

Comment: Do you have any person or group column with same user info in same list?

Comment: Do you want to limit this only for specific list view of other users should never (including other list views) see the items with other names?

Comment: one persone add invoices to the list and add names of persone which are responsible to see this items, so every persone see only his invoices. and creator see all items

Comment: Follow approach given in my answer below.

Comment: Hi @novice, did you try the approach given in my answer below, is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this using calculated formula in SharePoint.

You can try below to achieve your requirements:

1. Create a power automate flow on item creation (and/or item update - as per you requirements).
2. Break permissions inheritance on list item
3. Grant permissions to user email mentioned in "email" column
4. Grant permissions to Created By user email
5. Also grant permissions to site owners/admins for safer side

Follow below links for breaking permissions:

1. [Power Automate - Break Inheritance And Set List Item-Level Permissions In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharep/)
2. [Stop sharing an item or a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#stop-sharing-an-item-or-a-file)

Follow below links for granting permissions:

1. [Grant access to an item or a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#grant-access-to-an-item-or-a-folder)
2. [Setting SharePoint Permissions with Power Automate](https://steveknutson.blog/2021/12/10/setting-sharepoint-permissions-with-power-automate/)

Comment: thank you perfect.