# Power Automate "Grant access to an item or a folder" act differently for internal vs external users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a workflow which contain 2 "Grant access to an item or a folder" actions; one to add internal user to a document (named Test user) , while the second one to add external user to the same docuemnt (named NETCoreSharepoint@gmail.com user), as follow:-

[image]

now this result in adding the internal user directly to the document permission , while it will create a sharing link for the external user, as follow:-

[image]

so how i can standardize this and always add the users (internal or external ) directly to the document permission without creating links?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will be able to change the behavior of Standard actions provided by Microsoft. You can try granting permissions with REST API in flow, check links given in: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304174/sharepoint-list-how-to-limit-items-in-list-with-formula/304176#304176